# Break excel WorkBook Links

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink, vba

i tried to break all links of a workbook programmatically. I tried using the approach [Workbook.LinkSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.linksources(v=vs.80).aspx) Method but doesn't work, it return always null also if there are links.

```
 public static string BreakLinks(string excelfilename, string newexcelfile, bool close, Workbook mywrk)
        {
            string nomefile = excelfilename;
            Workbook mywrk = GetWorkBook(excelfilename);

            try
            {
                Array olinks = mywrk.LinkSources(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLink.xlExcelLinks) as Array;
                if (olinks != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= olinks.Length; i++)
                    {
                        mywrk.BreakLink((string)olinks.GetValue(i), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
                    }

                    SafeSaveCopyAs(mywrk, newexcelfile);
                    nomefile = newexcelfile;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            if (close) CloseWorkBook(ref mywrk);
            return nomefile;
        }
```

I used this vba code on the same document to verify if there are links or not and they are.

```
Sub main()
    Dim olinks As Object
    Dim v As Variant
    v = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    Dim first_link As String
    first_link = v(1)
    Debug.Print first_link
End Sub
```

Why VBA return the links and the c# approch doesn't? Any idea?

Comment: I feel you may have to re-look into syntax of your code. For example in c# code fragment as per msdn is ~for (int i = 1; i <= links.Length; i++)
    {
        this.OpenLinks((string)links.GetValue(i), true,
            Excel.XlLink.xlExcelLinks);
~ While in VBA code fragment for same purpose is nearly as following               ~Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To links.Length
        Me.OpenLinks(links(i), True, Excel.XlLink.xlExcelLinks)
    Next i~

Comment: My previous comment was for old versions. Latest c# code fragment as per msdn is ~object LinkSources(
 object Type
)~ While in VB code fragment for same purpose is ~Function LinkSources (
 Type As Object
) As Object~